# OpenLayers3 getting a type error when trying to save mouse position to variable

Tags: openlayers

In OpenLayers3 it shall be possible to save the current mouse position coordinates in a variable like this:

```
          map.on('click', function(evt){
            let coordinates = ol.proj.transform(evt.coordinate);
            // for debug purposes:
            console.log(`You clicked at ${coordinates}`);
          })
```

However, when I implement the code above it always returns `Uncaught TypeError: t is null`.

So there seems to be a parameter missing.

Which one is it and why do I have to overhand this parameter while others can just use above mentioned code?

Since this a planimetric fantasy map I use a custom projection. I read that OpenLayers integration of userProjections isn't fully implemented yet. However, everything else works fine like display of scale, display of the current mouse position in a seperate `<div>`, ... I even worked out a pretty neat search function for features using WFS.
But, at the end, I'll always fail on implementing this, I guess, pretty simple functionality.

Comment: In OL3 method `ol.proj.transform` expects also source and target CRS (see https://openlayers.org/en/v3.20.1/apidoc/ol.proj.html#.transform). Why are you using `ol.proj.transform`? In what CRS you want to display your coordinates? Without transform you will get coordinates in CRS of your view.

Comment: @TomazicM You pretty much hinted me the solution, which works. Since I read everywhere that o.proj.transform shall be the function to get mouse coordinates to map coordiantes, I didn't question it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@TomazicM gave me a good hint. Since I do not want to transform one coordinate into an other crs `ol.proj.transform` is not the right method.
Instead I want to use `ol.proj.toUserCoordinate`. Thus the correct snippet for this would be:

```
          map.on('click', function(evt){
            let coordinates = ol.proj.toUserCoordinate(evt.coordinate) // [x, y]
            // for debug purposes:
            console.log(`You clicked at ${coordinates}`);
          })
```

This may only work for me because I use a custom/user projection. **However, it worked now. :)**